# Convert array of objects to object of objects preserving interior

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have yet to see this specific solution, but if exists I would love to have a link. I pretty much have the following:

```
const obj = {"key":
[
  { "name": { "companyName": "Something" } },
  { "otherThing": { "coolThing": "coolThingName" } },
]}
```

Something in this format. I would like to literally just change it to:

```
const obj = {"key":
{
  { "name": { "companyName": "Something" } },
  { "otherThing": { "coolThing": "coolThingName" } },
}}
```

But I for some reason cannot for the life of me figure out how.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
const arr = [
  { 'value': 'val', 'another': 'yessir'},
  { 'value1': 'val1', 'another1': 'yessir1'},
  { 'value2': 'val2', 'another2': 'yessir2'},
  { 'value3': 'val3', 'another3': 'yessir3'},
];

const arrayToObject = (arry) => {
  let newObj = {};
  newObj = arry.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return { ...acc, ...cur };
  }, {});
  return newObj;
};
```

The issue with this is that it returns the entire segment into one large object, whereas I need to preserve the sub objects.

EDIT:
For clarification, here is my motivation:

The elasticsearch query I currently have is like this

```
"query": {
   "bool": {
      "must": [
          ]}}
```

But the proper elasticsearch syntax for the "must" is:

```
  "query": {
   "bool": {
      "must": {
          }}}
```

I am trying to run this conversion on the fly in my code

Comment: Isn't the 1st option just the main syntax? You want to change that?

Comment: array vs object. the second/wanted one is not a valid object.

Comment: May we know WHY??? This is doable: `{
   "name": { "companyName": "Something" } ,
   "otherThing": { "coolThing": "coolThingName" } 
}`

Comment: @NinaScholz is it not possible to have an object with nested sub objects?

Comment: Not like you did, no @JarredParr - Maybe share what you want to achieve, so we can propose a better solution. It would also help to share the problems you have with the array

Comment: @JarredParr yes but you need a key for each subobject

Comment: you need some keys for the objects.

Comment: I have edited to show more of how I'd intend to use it. I am taking JSON and running a conversion on it to get the array to be an object for an Elasticsearch query.

Comment: I see where I was going wrong

Comment: @NinaScholz I have changed my post to reflect it more clearly. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: it is stiil invalid, because you have something like `{ {}, {} }` which is not valid without keys, like `{ key1: {}, key2: {} }`

Comment: @NinaScholz Even if it's all nested in a single object?

Comment: it depends on your need. actually you did not supply a valid data structure for converting the array into the wanted??? format.

Comment: what's wrong with `var obj = { ...arr }` code? Your keys are not unique in all of your objects within your array.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  { "name": { "companyName": "Something" } },
  { "otherThing": { "coolThing": "coolThingName" } },
}
```

is not valid javascript object. Objects are `key: value` pairs

Like

```
{
  1: { "name": { "companyName": "Something" } },
  2: { "otherThing": { "coolThing": "coolThingName" } },
}


const arr = [
  { 'value': 'val', 'another': 'yessir'},
  { 'value1': 'val1', 'another1': 'yessir1'},
  { 'value2': 'val2', 'another2': 'yessir2'},
  { 'value3': 'val3', 'another3': 'yessir3'},
];

const arrayToObject = (arry) => {
  let newObj = {};
  arry.forEach((item, index) => {
    newObj[index] = item;
  }, {});
  return newObj;
};
```

Comment: @JarredParr Again this is not possible ```{"key":
{
  { "name": { "companyName": "Something" } },
  { "otherThing": { "coolThing": "coolThingName" } },
}}``` but instead ```{"key":
{
  1: { "name": { "companyName": "Something" } },
  2: { "otherThing": { "coolThing": "coolThingName" } },
}}``` or ```{"key":
{
  name": { "companyName": "Something" } ,
  otherThing": { "coolThing": "coolThingName" },
}}```

Answer (score -1):

This is doable:

```
{ 
  "name": { "companyName": "Something" } , 
  "otherThing": { "coolThing": "coolThingName" } 
}
```

```js
const arr = [
  { "name": { "companyName": "Something" } },
  { "otherThing": { "coolThing": "coolThingName" } },
], obj = {};
arr.forEach(function(item) {
  const key = Object.keys(item)[0];
  obj[key]=item[key];
})
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

Objects are key-value pairs and you have values without keys

```
{
  { "name": { "companyName": "Something" } },
  { "otherThing": { "coolThing": "coolThingName" } },
}
```

see the error in this snippet:

```js
const obj = {"key":
{
  { "name": { "companyName": "Something" } },
  { "otherThing": { "coolThing": "coolThingName" } },
}}
```

Either of the following are valid objects:

```js
    const obj = {
       "name": { "companyName": "Something" },
       "otherThing": { "coolThing": "coolThingName" },
    }
    
    console.log(obj)
```

or

```js
    const obj = {
      0: { "name": { "companyName": "Something" } },
      1: { "otherThing": { "coolThing": "coolThingName" } },
    }
    
    console.log(obj);
```

According to the elasticsearch docs, either of the following are valid:

```
{
    "query" : {
      "bool" : {
        "must" : [
          {
            "term" : {
                "user" : "foo"
            }
          },
          {
            "term" : {
                "user" : "bar"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

from here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html

and

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "query_string" : {
                    "query" : "some query string here"
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

from here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search.html

So, I think what you're trying to accomplish is this:

```js
    const yourArray = [
      { "name": { "companyName": "Something" } },
      { "otherThing": { "coolThing": "coolThingName" } },
    ]

    const preserveKeys = yourArray.reduce(function(acc, cur){
      for (let x in cur) {
        acc[x] = cur[x]
      }
      return acc;
    }, {});

    console.log(preserveKeys);
```

Just be careful you're not overwriting your keys with the ones from other objects